# Excel - How to include a count of blank cells in Pivot Table?

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

My Pivot Table totals the occurance of various strings in my column. Some of the cells are blank. I want the "blank" category to display a total count. How is this done?

[Similar unanswered question](https://superuser.com/questions/888455/pivot-table-not-showing-blank-values)

Excel for Mac 2011

Comment: See [this MS article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149169) for a workaround. Or create another field in your data set and hide it

Answer (score 2):

You can't count blank cells in an Excel Pivot table.  There are workarounds to this.  I have used conditional formatting in my table and counted the numbers.  See this article to see other workarounds.

[Count Blank Cells Workaround](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/149169)